# Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) in iOS integrate and how to use

Tags: ios, xcode

how to add the Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC)into the app and use the features. I am using this for the first time. Also tried find few tutorials for the same in google but was not successful. I need to know how to integrate that in my app and use the files of the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are succeed to integrate WAC.please share

Comment: Can you share some code please.

Comment: @shasha  HI, Are you done with integrating?

Answer (score 2):

to integrate WAC to your you need go through libraries in following link:

// take a look at eawifiunconfiguredaccessorybrowser , this class helps you to handle WAC, this would suffice your need.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/externalaccessory/eawifiunconfiguredaccessorybrowser?language=objc

i will brief you about adding WAC feature your app.

**step1**
enable WAC capabilities in app target ,as shown in picture below :

[enabling WAC in capabilities section of App target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7P3l.png)

**step2**
make use of eawifiunconfiguredaccessorybrowser methods :

*startSearchingForUnconfiguredAccessoriesMatchingPredicate --> helps to search for run configured accessories

*configure​Accessory:​with​Configuration​UIOn​View​Controller:​ --> does configuration by presenting system based screen.

it will work similar to WAC done through iOS setting app.

Comment: @n devaraj Hi, Can we also control video processor through wifi?

Comment: @AnuragSharma if you plan to communication with Process with MFI certificate you can refer to  link below https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/easession?language=objc

Comment: @n devaraj Thank you for your suggestion, Actually, I am connecting using NSStream now. As my hardware has IP and port number.